# Ignore Error org.jsoup.HttpStatusException... And Print Custom Message?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, jsoup, http-status-code-404

**What's Happening**

I'm trying to parse 500 different links to retrieve emails from, this links are old and some of the websites have been shut so its normal to receive 404 error, however it terminates the whole process.

Ps: The code below is ran in a loop

**Code**

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link.group()).timeout(20*1000).get();
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(doc.toString());
                if (m.find()) {             
                    String email = m.group();              
                    System.out.println(m.group() + " - " + organizationName.group());


                }
                else {System.out.println("No Emails Found");};
```

**Error**

```
     Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404
```

**What I want**

Is there a way I can tell Java/Eclipse to ignore this error and instead print "Invalid Website" in console and keep the process going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
....
} catch (HttpStatusException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid website");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.jsoup.HttpStatusException` is not the only exception that can be thrown by [`org.jsoup.Connection.get()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#get--)

> ```
> MalformedURLException - if the request URL is not a HTTP or HTTPS URL, or is otherwise malformed
> HttpStatusException - if the response is not OK and HTTP response errors are not ignored
> UnsupportedMimeTypeException - if the response mime type is not supported and those errors are not ignored
> SocketTimeoutException - if the connection times out
> IOException - on error
> ```

However, since all of these implement `java.io.IOException` you should use that in the `try`/`catch`, not just `org.jsoup.HTTPStatusException`.

```
try {
....
} catch (IOException e) { 
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```